# Get Ionic Storage values - retrieve values from async function

Tags: angular, angular6, ionic4

If i am storing token and user id in Ionic storage how can I retrieve their values?

so far, I implemented something like this

**auth.service.ts**

```
getToken() {
    return this.storage.get(TOKEN_KEY);
}

getId() {
    this.storage.get(ID);
}
```

**crud.service.ts**

```
getOne(url: string, id: string): any {
    return this.http.get('/api/v1' + url + '/' + id, {
        headers: this.getHeaders()
    })
}


getHeaders() {
    return new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  this.authServ.getToken()})
}
```

**my.component.ts**

```
 user: User = new User();
 id: string;

 constructor(private crudServ: CrudService, private authServ: AuthService) {
    this.id = this.authServ.getId();
 }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.crudServ.getOne('/users', this.id).subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data;
    })
 }
```

I know that Ionic storage get is async function, but I cannot find solution how to use that function to retrieve token and id and use that values inside other functions

Answer (score 0):

in your ts :

```
user: User = new User();
 id: string;

 constructor(private crudServ: CrudService, private authServ: AuthService) {
    this.id = "";
 }

 ngOnInit() {
    this.authServ.getId().then(data => {
        this.id = data;
        this.crudServ.getOne('/users', this.id).subscribe(data => {
            this.user = data;
          });
       });
 }
```

Comment: if i console.log(this.id) outside of constructor, in ngOnInit function, it is still undefined..but I need to use that value in that function and some other functions

Comment: I update my code for you. You juste need to modify your component, I you don't need to change your service. storage return already a promise :)

Comment: I'm just wondering is it possible to store value from storage in local component variable if I wanna use this value in couple functions instead calling this.authServ.getId().then() function each time?

Comment: well, you can create global variables in your auth.service and set them when you call the this.authServ.getId() function from your app.component.ts. So you juste need to set your id in your my.component.ts or another one by using this.id = this.authserv.id

Comment: I know that, i was thinking that I can retrieve values from ionicstorage somehow. So, there is no point to use Ionic.storage in this case, I need change back to localStorage

Comment: Yes, it is more better.